# Unclear why Cypress' Chrome browser does not render feed of videos

Tags: cypress

Basic Cypress question here about how to access videos from the following site, using Cypress. Visiting https://www.tiktok.com/tag/cats?lang=en will show an endless scroll.

I'd like to visit the page in the context of cypress, but when I do so while the site furniture appears, the videos do not appear and the page hangs at loading:

```
<main class="share-layout-main">
    <div class="jsx-2893588005 video-feed"></div>
    <div class="jsx-1970579021 jsx-1005258868 tiktok-loading feed-loading"></div>
</main>
```

This is my specfile:

```
describe('tags', () => {
  it.only('...', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.tiktok.com/tag/cats?lang=en');
  });
});
```

Chrome websecurity:

```
{
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I chose the electron browser this worked for me. It did not work with Chrome however.